# Create new another workspace

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create another workspace alongside with current existing one.
I have a working workspace named 'catkin_ws' my new workspace is 'reemron_ws'

when i do
cd ~/reemron_ws
and type
catkin_make
I'm getting the error:

The specified base path "/home/lizi/reemron_ws" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace

I pay attention that the CMakeList.txt in my new workspace is linked to other file.
This is the output of ls -l (in reemron_ws folder)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lizi lizi   49 Apr 30 14:07 CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake

I know the error says that catkin_make must run from the root of the workspace but I'm at the root of the workspace.
And suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260706/create-new-another-workspace/) by [Robotics2233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30209/robotics2233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was i run the command:

catkin_init_workspace

at the root of the workspace instead at /src

I delete the folder and create again and its OK.

---

Originally posted by [Robotics2233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30209/robotics2233/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0